# ORACLE SQL Ordering issue

Tags: sql, oracle

This is how my list looks like:

```
STUDENTID            COURSEID      PLACE
-------------------- -------- ----------
1                    XXX123            1 
2                    YYY123            2 
2                    XXX123            3
```

The PLACE is a sequence for when the STUDENTID registerd on the COURSEID, so the first to ever register for a course is given the number 1 and so on.

The problem I'm having is that I need to re-arrange the list to look something like this:

```
STUDENTID            COURSEID      PLACE
-------------------- -------- ----------
1                    XXX123            1 
2                    YYY123            1 
2                    XXX123            2
```

So PLACE is a number which order the COURSEID. When i delete a row in the table the second person need to be numbered 1, a.s.o.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the `row_number()` function:

```
select studentid, courseid, row_number() over (partition by courseid order by place) as place
from table t;
```

Because you want this to be recalculated when there are changes to the data, I would not suggest that you change the underlying data.  Just create a view that has this logic:

```
create view v_courseplace as
    select studentid, courseid, row_number() over (partition by courseid order by place) as place
    from table t;
```

Unless you have a really large table, performance should not be an issue.

Comment: Indeed. If the data you are wanting (as a column) can be deducted from "real data" you should not store the deducatable data, but rather have it as a report. That could include creating a view, but you can also write a procedure to have the data returned.